# DDD +hibernate+integration with soa

Tags: hibernate, domain-driven-design, soa

at first We have a model like

```
class Person extends EntityBase<Person, PersonNumber>{
 private PersonNumber personNumber;
 private String name;
 private Contact contact;
 private String educationLevel;
}
class Contact extends ValueObjectBase<Contact> {
  private String phone;
  private String address;
  private String contactPerson;
}
```

but now we have to integration with anther system name "System DC", the original person table been take apart, the personNumber,name, phone,address column now moved to "System DC" . And "SystemDC" provide a database view "DC_PersonView" to us for query.If we need to create a person we have to do call webservice from "SystemDC".

so we define a personDTO like

```
 class PersonDTO{
 private PersonNumber personNumber;
 private String name;
 private String phone;
 private String address;
 }
```

plan 1:

1. refactor person to IPerson interface
2. define a PersonWrape Class

   ```
   class PersonWrape implements IPerson {
    private Person person;
    private PersonDTO personDTO;
   }
   ```
3. in PersonWrape repository

   ```
   void SavePerson(IPerson person) {
     systemDC.saveWebservice(person.getPersonDTO);
     personRepository.save(person);// map the column not in systemDC like  educationLevel to our person table.
     }
   ```

plan 2: 
  only modify the personRepository:

```
    void SavePerson(IPerson person) {
      PersonDTO personDTO = PersonDTO.fromEntiry(person);
      systemDC.saveWebservice(personDTO);
      personRepository.save(person);// map the column not in systemDC like  educationLevel
      }
```

but query person will be truble..

How do we model under this situation? please give us some suggestions.

Comment: Does the person entity need to exist in both systems (bounded contexts)?

Comment: Yes,In our System we need full Person entity. But we have to update Person entity like 1.update our database 2.update the other column by webservice..

Comment: So system DC just needs a copy of a subset of person data? Does system DC store any person data not in your system? Does system DC manipulate person data that needs to be reflected in your system?

Comment: System DC hold the subset data of the original person.Does system DC store any person data not in your system?  Yes! Does system DC manipulate person data that needs to be reflected in your system? Yes.We need full person data in our business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have an integration scenario between two bounded contexts (BC). In these scenarios, it is often possible to discern a relationship BCs that can determine how entity changes are propagated.

In your use case is appears that you have a single notion of a person (each person has a single identity shared among BCs), but you have 2 different BCs where a person is manifest with each BC containing and managing different person data. Then the save operation that you discuss is actually two save operations, one in each BC. Each BC saves information that it is interested in. If you have a use case, such as a UI form that accepts person information for both BCs, that use case should send the save command to both BCs explicitly. Your plan 2 is closest to this approach, however I would not place that code in the repository. Instead, I would call two distinct services directly from the presentation layer or the application layer.

What you can also consider is whether there is some sort of downstream relationship between your original BC (let's call it **A**) and System **DC**. For instance, if **DC** is downstream from A for person data, then instead of calling both services explicitly during a save, you can implement an event-driven approach. With this approach, **A** would publish events regarding changes to person data and an integration point between **A** and **DC** would subscribe to those events and make the appropriate modifications in **DC**. Note that this approach is usually [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). Overall, the event-driven approach is more complicated but also more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you use DTO's and don't expose the domain modal when using SOA. Anything else would be a mess in the end (trying to work with the domain model in the client applications).

The problem are however that you try to expose the domain model as a CRUD SOA service. You can't let the SOA service change any field of an arbitary entity. It has to follow the domain model and the methods and services that you have defined in it.

For instance. If you have a method in the `User` class that is called `CalculateAge` then create a SOA method called `CalculateUserAge` and not one which is called `UpdateUser`.

Comment: "trying to work with the domain model in the client applications" That's what we want to do. Because in our application ,we already have a method like 'PersonRepository.save(person)' but at this time,the original person is been take apart into two pieces..